# How to configure http/manager/html link of Tomcat 8.5?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using Tomcat 8.5.3 on Linux.

Can anyone help me to create a Tomcat manager GUI link so that I can
access the manager through the server IP?

```
http://(Domain Ip)/manager/html
```

It always shows `403 Access denied`.

Here is the contents of `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

    <tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
                  version="1.0">
       <role rolename="tomcat"/>
      <role rolename="role1"/>
       <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
      <user username="tomcat" password="***" roles="manager-gui"/>

    </tomcat-users>
```

I wanted to reload any project through the GUI's reload button.

I am facing one more problem. Whenever I change my Java files, the
server doesn't reflect the changes until I restart Apache Tomcat or I reload the project.

Comment: I have similar problem using tomcat 8.5.5 on osx. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: @ piotrdab: Please see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go to

```
/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.3/webapps/manager/META-INF
```

> Open context.xml
>
> and Comment the below line in context.xml

```
 <!--
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="some ip" />
  -->
```